Accessing files listed in a data block
I have seen a few questions about data dependencies in bazel but nothing I have tried seems to work.
My project has this structure:
|-- BUILD.bazel
|-- resources
|   |-- gold
|   `-- inputs
|       `-- my
|           `-- pkg
|               `-- ISimple.java
`-- src
    `-- my
        `-- tests
            `-- BasicTests.java

I have the following in my BUILD file:
filegroup(
    name = "test_sources",
    srcs = glob(
        ["src/**/*.java"],
    ),
)

filegroup(
    name = "test_resources",
    srcs = glob(
        ["resources/**/*"],
    ),
)

java_library(
    name = "allTests",
    ...
    data = [":test_resources"],  # Just for good measure
    deps = [
        ...
    ],    
)

java_test(
    name = "Simple",
    srcs = [":test_sources"],
    test_class = "my.tests.BasicTests",
    data = [":test_resources"],   # I thought this would make my resources available
    deps = [
        ":allTests",
        ...
    ]
)

My first attempt was actually to put the resources in the test jar file and read them from there but I kept getting a FileSystemNotFoundException being thrown when I tried accessing them from the test code.
So, now I am trying to simply make them available during testing by putting them in the data attribute and reading them directly.  However, no matter what I do in my test code I am getting a FileNotFoundException being thrown.
I have tried opening:

"resources/inputs/my/pkg/ISimple.java"
"inputs/my/pkg/ISimple.java"
System.getenv("JAVA_RUNFILES") + "/resources/inputs/my/pkg/ISimple.java"
System.getenv("JAVA_RUNFILES") + "/inputs/my/pkg/ISimple.java"
System.getenv("RUNFILES_DIR") + "/resources/inputs/my/pkg/ISimple.java"
System.getenv("RUNFILES_DIR") + "/inputs/my/pkg/ISimple.java"
System.getenv("PWD") + "/resources/inputs/my/pkg/ISimple.java"
System.getenv("PWD") + "/inputs/my/pkg/ISimple.java"

But I always get a FileNotFoundException being thrown.
I have written a second 'test' that executes a 'tree' command from the PWD directory and puts the results in an assertion (that fails) and verified that I do see resources/... from the working directory.  However, I still get the FileNotFoundException when trying to open the file (ISimple.java).
What am I missing here?

Sorry to waste everyone's time.  This was an error on my part.  I had an internal pathing problem.  Simply opening and reading the file from <path to project from workspace root>/resources/... does, in fact, work.  Though, I was led to believe from the docs that reading from resources/... should work, this doesn't seem to be the case - at least for projects not at the WORKSPACE root.
